# access and update a python3 set defined in the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am using https://github.com/sciunto/python-bibtexparser as a library module for my code(installed with pip3). So, I don't have writing access to the module.

But, the set it is using is rather limited, as defined in `standard_types` in https://github.com/sciunto/python-bibtexparser/blob/master/bibtexparser/bibdatabase.py.

Is it possible, that, I redefine/append the set from the calling code? e.g.

```
#foo.py
import bibtexparser

#redefine standard_types
bibtexparser.STANDARD_TYPES = set([the complete set I need])

#or append the standard_types
bibtexparser.STANDARD_TYPES.update = set([append to the set])
```

?

**Update**: Actually I cant access the variable STANDARD_TYPES. I am trying to do:

```
from bibtexparser import bibdatabase as bd

class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, application, giofile=None):
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow.__init__(self,
                                       application=application,
                                       default_width=1000,
                                       default_height=200,
                                       border_width=5)


        print(bd)
        print(bd.STANDARD_TYPES)
```

Which is yielding:

```
    <module 'bibtexparser.bibdatabase' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bibtexparser/bibdatabase.py'>
......
        print(bd.STANDARD_TYPES)
    AttributeError: module 'bibtexparser.bibdatabase' has no attribute 'STANDARD_TYPES'
```

Comment: Possibly.  Try it!  For appending, use the `|=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like other parts of the package perform `from bibtextparser import STANDARD_TYPES`, so you can't just replace it; the modules that have already imported it will keep the old version. Using `update` would work fine though you need to fix your syntax:

```
bibtexparser.STANDARD_TYPES.update({append to the set})
```

That said, it looks like `BibTexParser` can be initialized passing it `ignore_nonstandard_types=True` and it won't even check `STANDARD_TYPES`, which is probably what you really want; it doesn't involve hacky monkey-patching at all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But, if I am doing `from bibtexparser.bibdatabase import STANDARD_TYPES`, Its showing error:
    `print(bibtexparser.STANDARD_TYPES)
AttributeError: module 'bibtexparser' has no attribute 'STANDARD_TYPES'`

Comment: @BaRud: You used `from x import y` syntax. Don't qualify the name. `print(STANDARD_TYPES)` would work.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that...but thats not working either, Please check the OP, once again.

Comment: @BaRud: I can't see why that would happen; the source code you link would have that work. Figure out where `STANDARD_TYPES` is defined in your code. That said, did you read the other part of my answer? Monkey-patching is a brittle hack, and the library you're using already lets you opt out of type checking. Why not just opt-out instead of using brittle hacks?

Comment: sorry, but where you found that option? I cant trace that.